# Where do I find the source package for `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs` 8.2.0-3?

Tags: mingw-w64

I need the source package for the `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs-8.2.0-3` package. I believe this is generated from the mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc source package. Looking in the [repository](http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/sources/) I can find `mingw-w64-gcc-7.3.0-2.src.tar.gz` but nothing for `gcc-8.*`.

Most other packages have a simple relationship between binary and source package names. In a few cases (GCC is one) a single source package is used to generate multiple binary packages. However the naming is usually fairly obvious, and version numbers stay the same. I can't find any GCC-related source packages with the "8.2.0" version number.

Does anyone know where to get the source for the gcc-libs mingw package from?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download). You can find GCC 8.1.0.

Comment: I've got MinGW installed and running fine, thanks. Its the particular source package that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Open an issue on https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues

Apparently the maintainer forgot to upload the source package, or some script is failing.